# How to extract value from XML payload using Shell script

Tags: java, shell, unix

I have runtime XML file which has predefined format and Its being created in Jenkins workspace. I just want to parse the XML payload by using shell script.

Sample Payload:

```
 <test-results>
     <test-method status="FAIL" name="flowVISA" duration-ms="843329" data-provider="533w43werwer" finished-at="2018-11-01T23:30:48Z">
       <params>
         <param index="0">
           <value>
           <![CDATA[ account_number:22988419 ]]>
           </value>
         </param>
         <param index="1">
           <value>
           <![CDATA[ txn_id:6wdadfsad2134330L ]]>
           </value>
         </param>
         <param index="2">
           <value>
           <![CDATA[ amount:1100 ]]>
           </value>
          </param>
          <param index="3">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[ currency:USD ]]>
            </value>
          </param>
          <param index="4">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[Id:11a09 ]]>
            </value>
          </param>
          <param index="5">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[Name:Consumer [testId=AS1-TC2, description=Txn amount; wallet -Bal, BA,CC,VISA Credit; Consumer - CC;No other preference set]]]>
            </value>
          </param>
        </params>
     </test-method>
     <test-method status="PASS" name="flowVISA" duration-ms="843329" data-provider="533w43werwer" finished-at="2018-11-01T23:30:48Z">
         <params>
           <param index="0">
              <value>
              <![CDATA[ account_number:22988419 ]]>
              </value>
           </param>
           <param index="1">
             <value>
             <![CDATA[ txn_id:6wdadfsad2134330L ]]>
             </value>
           </param>
        </params>
      </test-method>
      <test-method status="FAIL" name="flowVISA" duration-ms="843329" data-provider="533w43werwer" finished-at="2018-11-01T23:30:48Z">
        <params>
           <param index="0">
              <value>
              <![CDATA[ account_number:22988419 ]]>
              </value>
           </param>
           <param index="1">
              <value>
              <![CDATA[Name:Consumer [testId=AS1-TC3, description=Txn amount; wallet -Bal, BA,CC,VISA Credit; Consumer - CC;No other preference set]]]>
              </value>
           </param>
         </params>
      </test-method>
  </test-results>
```

The above payload I have to read the status of test-method if it's "FAIL" then I need to get the "testId" value from that particular test method. The above payload I have 3 test methods only two had status Failed I need to fetch both Test id and assign to variable as like below

**Expected Output:**

```
  fetchResult = AS1-TC2,AS1-TC3
```

I just need to fetch the "testId" of failed test-methods and assign it to variable with comma separated using shell script.

I tried the below lines but It doesn't return the entire test-method tags

```
   failedTC=`grep "test-method.*FAIL" results.xml | sed -e 's/^.*test-instance-name="(.*)-----.*/\1/'
```

**Output:**

```
   <test-method status="FAIL" name="flowVISA" duration-ms="843329" data-provider="533w43werwer" finished-at="2018-11-01T23:30:48Z">
```

I want to return entire `<test-method> ... </test-method>` for status="FAIL"

Any leads....

Comment: Your file is not valid XML.

Comment: This is a big payload. I can't upload entire payload here. So I just cut the piece where I need to extract values.

Comment: I suggest to add a root node in your example.

Comment: Sure. I done the same.

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following xmlstarlet and sed command:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -c "test-results/test-method[@status='FAIL']/params/param/value[contains(.,'testId')]" file | sed -n 's/.*testId=\([^,]\+\),.*/\1/p'
```

`-T`: raw test (without XML node).
`-t`: template
`-c`: Xpath expression

`[@status='FAIL']` is the test on the attribute `status`.

`value[contains(.,'testId')]` tests if the `value` node contains that specific string.

The `sed` command extracts the wanted string.

Comment: xmlstartlet is not identified in Jenkins

Comment: Is it possible to get the current entire XML values using bash command. like the entire <test-method> ...</test-method> for status=FAIL

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan You likely need to install the tool on your Jenkins host...

Comment: It's remote box. I dnt have access to install tools over there. Pls give me some suggestion to do that. I used below lines but It's not return as expected  Example:   failedTC=`grep "test-method.*FAIL"  results.xml | sed -e 's/^.*test-instance-name="\(.*\)-----.*/\1/'   but Its not return entire <test-method> tags values

Comment: Updated the question